# uploading csv file to solr using solr admin panel

Tags: solr

I want to upload my csv file into my solr core using solr's admin panel. I'm doing something like this image

[image: I'm getting this error]

I looked from other forums but I don't find any answer. Could you give me some advise?

I opened my `.csv` file with notepad and it looks like this

[image: my csv file]

Comment: Why are you uploading to the `/extract` request handler? That uses Tika behind the scenes to extract content from rich data types. Use the regular `/update` handler with the content type set to `text/csv`. You can see the [complete set of options for the CSV handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html#csv-update-parameters) in the reference guide.

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried it before it gives me this error **Unsupported ContentType: application/vnd.ms-excel Not in: [application/xml, application/csv, application/json, text/json, text/csv, text/xml, application/javabin]**

Comment: It seems like you're submitting an _excel file_ and not an actual CSV? Did you explicitly set the content type to text/csv? What does the file show if you open it in a text editor directly?

Comment: @MatsLindh I added my csv file's image.

Comment: Are you using the `post` tool when you get that error message? I'm suspecting this might be because of a mime type registered for the file on your computer. Try setting the content-type explicitly in the request as the web interface allows. Also see [Indexing CSV](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/post-tool.html#indexing-csv) and the `-type` parameter (set it to `-type text/csv`).

Comment: @MatsLindh When I use post tool with command prompt I'm setting it **text/csv**, but when I try to upload with solr's admin panel **/update request handler**, it's gives me this error.